# Mono Class as shared library?

Tags: linux, mono

.Net class can be compiled into a shared library (.dll). Can a mono class be compiled into a shared library in linux (.so)? how?

Answer (score 4):

.Net `.dll` files are not *real*, i.e. **native**, shared libraries. By default, Mono also produces and consumes `.dll` files, using the same assembly format as Microsoft .Net. Both runtimes generate native code from this intermediate format during runtime.

However, it is possible to perform Ahead-Of-Time (AOT) compilation and save the resulting `.so` file to disk (Microsoft .Net equivalent of this is the `ngen.exe` native image generation and cache). When you invoke Mono with the `--aot` flag, it will save the native code in form of a `.so` library and use it whenever the same file is loaded again. You probably also want to add the `-O=all` flag to enable all optimizations (some of them are disabled by default because they are costly to perform).

However, please bear in mind that the cached native library probably won't be usable for linking into native programs.